# How to remove Schlage deadbolt?

Tags: lock

I want to remove a Schlage deadbolt so I can re-key it.  I don't have the key (previous owner lost it).  The deadbolt has keyholes on both sides.  Here's a view of the inside face:

[image]

The outside face is the same except it doesn't have the "rivet heads" on either side of the keyhole.  Here's a pic of the bolt itself:

[image]

Comment: Some locks require you to turn the cylinder 45°, before you can gain access to the screws. I'm not familiar with your model, so I can't say for sure.  A quick phone call to Schalge may be the easiest way to figure out how to remove it.  Depending on the lock, rekeying without the original key can range anywhere from difficult to impossible. So you may find that you have to replace the locks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first picture the round disk looking objects on either side of the keyway are screw covers that are driven after the screws are tightened.

A strong sharp object, something like a chisel that you don't mind getting dull would do the trick. The pin that is in the screw head isn't very long so the cover will fall off readily after the cover starts lifting out. After the covers are removed, the screws are removed using a Phillips head screwdriver. The screws under the covers are #1 the screws in the latch are #2.

Comment: Thanks.  A small nail point popped one screw cover off; the other required a minute's work with the awl on a pocket knife.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a Fleetwood manufactured home 1983 and the dead bolt looks a lot like picture number 1, but it doesn't say Schlage and its silver in color.

To remove or tighten it up, just insert the key and start to turn it in the lock direction and watch the two screw holes open up, they will open so you can see the phillips head screws before the dead bolt starts to come out.